# Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have code to check for the existence of a blob and its size that works fine in my development machine but when I publish to the production server it gives me the exception:

> Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob

Here is the code:

```
CloudStorageAccount v_StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(v_ConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient v_BlobClient = v_StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer v_Container = v_BlobClient.GetContainerReference(v_Containerstring);
CloudBlockBlob v_Blob = v_Container.GetBlockBlobReference(p_Name);

v_Blob.FetchAttributes();
```

I have tested around with fiddler and found out that when running in the server, the response header does not have any of the x-ms- tags, although the request headers are identical in both machines.

Request Header:

```
    HEAD http://XXX/90f5a5f1-9f6f-46bc-bbf6-21d77b8955ed HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/8.2.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.36399; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)
x-ms-version: 2017-04-17
x-ms-client-request-id: XXX
x-ms-date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 13:44:14 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey XXX:XXX
Host: XXX
```

Response in development machine:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 504014
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-MD5: /i5aFVWYlPqZjHvU+gxcbw==
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 20:22:02 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8D542672BB913FD"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 04155a59-001e-000d-58e5-8ab906000000
x-ms-version: 2017-04-17
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted: false
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 14:04:56 GMT
```

Response in production server:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 504014
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-MD5: /i5aFVWYlPqZjHvU+gxcbw==
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 20:22:02 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8D542672BB913FD"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 13:44:14 GMT
```

I don't know what I'm missing here, but, most important, how to make this code work on the production server?

**Edited**

To clarify some aspects:

- Development machine: my notebook with windows 10 + visual studio 2017
- Production server: virtual machine with windows server 2012 standard + sql server standard (no visual studio) + .net framework 4.5 enabled (project is 4.5)
- The server is on-premises, local, on the same network as my machine
- Using nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage 8.7
- All calls are to the same storage account and same Blob object, no emulator involved

The exception occurs at call to `v_Blob.FetchAttributes()`.

The same exception occurs also if I call `v_Blob.Exists()`.

I'm sure the blob is a Block Blob, the two calls (one from my development machine and other from production server) are to the same account and same Blob object, with the exact same parameters (connection string, container string and blob name). In my development machine all works fine.

Stack trace from exception:

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.FetchAttributes(AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 1619
at AzureDataMigration.Class.ConfereDocsMigrados.createBlockBlob(String p_Name, Int64 p_IdCompany, Int64 p_IdDocumentConfigType, StorGlobalHistoricalDocsEntities p_Model)
at AzureDataMigration.Class.ConfereDocsMigrados.Confere()
```

Comment: Are you pointing to the same storage account, with both your local-dev and production code? Or are you using the storage emulator (or different storage account) locally? Please edit your question to clarify. It would also help to know which line of code is throwing the error (along with the exact error details). Also - we don't know anything about what you mean by "production server" so there's not much to suggest...

Comment: Are you trying to call GetBlockBlobReference() against a page blob?

Comment: Hi, edited the post to clarify these questions. If you have any other doubts, please let me know. Thanks